# Is there a distributed web hosting platform that allows for custom nginx configs?

Tags: nginx, static, cloudflare

I've got a static site I'd like to host in a distributed fashion (i.e. on cloudflare). The one restriction I have is I need the exact same response regardless of the path. I.e. `/foo` returns the same html response as `/`. Is there a distributed hosting provider out there for static pages that can accomplish that? Right now I've got a custom nginx config on a vps which works fine, but I'd prefer having a distributed host for latency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily with Cloudflare rewrite rules -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/url-rewrite/create-dashboard